# Time Tracking software with Project Overview

Tags: time, project-management

Does anyone know of time tracking software like "toggl", that gives very basic project,task, time recording but that will let you add a start and end date for each project so you can just see how many projects there are lined up in your yearly calendar.  We don't want all the other high level functionality, just time tracking and the ability to see projects in a yearly calendar.  I can't find one anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Time Doctor](http://www.timedoctor.com). It has time tracking, can take random screenshots at any time, and lots of useful features that other software don’t have. We mainly used it to monitor our freelancers so we’ll have an idea on how they spend their time in doing productive things.